# Firebase error saving rules - Line 10: String can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"

Tags: firebase, rules

I follow the guide (https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/insecure-rules#database) and try to change the rules.
[But I have an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N5fC.png)

Can anyone expalain what is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you are receiving is due to some inconsistency in the documentation - The `/` character is disallowed. I've managed to publish a similar set of rules by changing it to nested paths.

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      "$uid": { 
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I'm assuming you are using Firebase Realtime Database. If you are using Firestore,  use `request.auth.id` instead

Answer (score 2):

I wrote to support and they told me there was a bug in their documentation. And the correct answer is:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users" :{
      "$uid": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *firebaser here* Sorry about the confusing mistake in our docs. I'm glad that our support team (and jloh) spotted it. I just went ahead fixed this (and two similar mistakes that I could find) on the page you linked, which should be published in our docs soon.